# Creating an absolute, yet variable, reference in VBA

Tags: vba, excel

First time poster here, I've been searching for the last hour without success so I'm turning to asking for help... My limited VBA knowledge might be a factor here.

I'm creating a quick macro that will sum values cumulatively. I regularly use =SUM($A$2:A2) and AutoFill down to get a cumulative sum. While I can be very quick at doing this, I have to do it several times per day in various sheets. My goal was to have the absolute $A$2 reference to be variable based on the current selected cell.

So let's assume I am trying to add this formula to cell B2. I know I can do:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C1:RC[-1])"`

However, this formula is unusable if my starting cell is anything but B2 and I am trying to cumulatively sum data in various columns.

Is it possible to have VBA count the number of columns between the selected cell and A2 and use this as a variable to set the absolute reference? Such as:

`ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2Cvar:RC[-1])"
where var is =COUNTA(R2C1:ActiveCell)+COUNTBLANK(R2C1:ActiveCell)-1`

I know the above code isn't valid, but it's the only way I can think of explaining what I'm trying to achieve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to concatenate your formula eg

```
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R2C" & var & ":RC[-1])"
```

But to get your variable you can do

```
    var = (ActiveCell.Column - 1)
```

Comment: you need spaces before and after the "&"'s, VBE will not do it automatically

Comment: Dave, thanks for the added info. I would've been stuck without that knowledge :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like:

```
Sub ytrewq()
    Dim s As String

    With ActiveCell
        s = .Offset(0, -1).Address(0, 0)
        .Formula = "=SUM($A$2:" & s & ")"
    End With
End Sub
```

The `Offset()` generates the address of the cell "just to the left".

Comment: I ended up going with the other solution provided, but I wanted to thank you for the submission. Perhaps I didn't formulate my question properly, but the formula you supplied would always lead to A2 to be the starting cell of my Sum formula, however that part has to be variable in the formula.